# You have reached the question limit

Tags: support, questions, limits

I received a message I have reached the question limit when I tried to ask a question. I wrote three questions last two weeks with 0 votes.

I am now answering other questions in hope I will be able to ask questions.

How does this process work? What should I do?

Comment: And since this is about Stack Overflow, this is a cross-site dupe of [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542)